Issue with webview and display modal in ios vs android
Using react-native-webview library, I'm encountering different behavior on Android and IOS in regard to how a modal that contains input field that opened will be displayed.
The issue occurs when focusing on an input field, as expected the keyboard opens but on IOS the modal get squashed whereas on android the content is displaying fine.
See screenshot below:

I wonder if there is a particular trick to adjust IOS behavior in this case?
We have such requirement to display some pages written in React.js (that we control) in the app via web-view, and so I have access to source code for this modal on the web which looks something like:
.modal {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    border-radius: 8px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 995;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

Environment:
OS: IOS, any version
react-native-webview: Version 13.2.2
react-native: Version 0.72.6
I am a bit clueless where to look, honestly. Looked up similar issues on Stack Overflow and the library GitHub repo but no luck.
I could inspect the same page on IOS simulator on safari web inspector and play with properties, but issue is not present
safari

Try using KeyboardAvoidingView, as follows:
  import React from 'react';
  import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';

  //[...]

  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
    style={styles.container}
  >
    //Your modal here
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>

Why do you need to change the behavior for IOS?:
According to the docs:

Android and iOS both interact with this prop differently. On both iOS and Android, setting behavior is recommended.


Thanks for the answer but I think you did not get idea. I am using react-native-webview to display some pages of our web app where the modal is displayed

@oldschoolstarsman Maybe I really didn't, could you share some code of how you set up react-native-webview? The CSS code itself does not help that much. But, you can try using KeyboardAvoidingView before the react-native-webview component, that should help.

<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'} style={{ flex: 1 }}>         <WebView           source={{             uri: params.navigationUrl.toString(),             headers: params.customHeaders,           }}           // ...other props not relevant         />       </KeyboardAvoidingView>
It is wrapped with KeyboardAvoidingView :/
